# How to verify of the origin of transactions on endorsing peer locally?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm studying the architecture of Hyperledger Fabric. I'm curious that how the endorsing peer can verify the origination of a transaction locally.

According to the documentation, when the submitting client send a transaction to endorsing peers, each endorsing peer verifies the client's signature. As far as I know, the signature is the message encrypted by the client's private key. To verify the signature, the endorsing peer needs the client's public key.

So, my question is that, from where the endorsing peer gets the client's public key? I guess that the public key is inside the genesis block for the channel which is generated by `configtxgen` tool because all peers on the same channel have this genesis block. Is it correct? Or does a transaction contain the client's public key(a.k.a the client's certificate) like the https connection? (But, according to the documentation, there is no room for the client's public key on the message format.)

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the genesis block doesn't have public keys of network nodes, only of root CAs and intermediate CAs.

Inside the transaction, the identity of the client is encoded.
Fabric v1.0 comes only with identities based on x509 certificates.
The public key is inside the certificate.

The signature doesn't contain the certificate. It's just the signature itself.
The certificate is included in the SignatureHeader of the transaction (in the creator field) which is, part of the transaction.
https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/d9c320297bd2a4eff2eb253ce84dc431ef860972/protos/common/common.proto#L113-L119

```
message SignatureHeader {
    // Creator of the message, specified as a certificate chain
    bytes creator = 1;

    // Arbitrary number that may only be used once. Can be used to detect replay attacks.
    bytes nonce = 2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your answer feels logical to me. According to the doc, `PROPOSE` message format is `<PROPOSE,tx,[anchor]>` and `tx` format is `<clientID,chaincodeID,txPayload,timestamp,clientSig>`. As far as I know, the signature is the other fields(clientID, ...etc.) encrypted by the client's private key. So, do you mean that `clientSig` contains the client's certificate in addition to the encrypted other fields? Or is the certificate included in a transaction, but the doc doesn't mention it as a part of `PROPOSE` message format?

Comment: Why would the signature be encrypted? The purpose is to provide proof of ownership for all, therefore it is not encrypted but anyone (that has the transaction, hence has the identity, hence has the public key) can verify it.

I updated the answer, take a look